# Can't write to ACF custom field in a WooCommerce order

Tags: php, woocommerce

I can't write a value to an ACF custom field on a WooCommerce order. I can read the same field. How can I update this ACF field on the order?

```
    // autocomplete virtual order + set backorder flag
    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'ke_set_backorder_flag');
    function ke_set_backorder_flag($order_id)
    {
      if ( ! $order_id ) {
           return;
    }
    global $product;
    //get an instance of the WC_order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // loop to get the order items from WC_Order_Item_Product objects
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

          //only look at line items (products)
          if ( $item['type'] == 'line_item' ) {
            $_product = $item->get_product();
            $ke_stock_qty = $_product->get_stock_quantity();
            //check if backorder
            if ( $ke_stock_qty < 1 ) {

                // TEST dst - read ke_stock ACF custom field
                $field_key='field_604a3d0d86088';
                $ke_stock_value = get_field( $field_key );

                // TEST write the actual stock qty in ke_stock
                update_field( $field_key, $ke_stock_qty );
            }
          }
        }
     }
```

My goal eventually is to set a boolean field as a backorder flag which I can show in the order view. But for now I'm just trying to update a text field.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Note that *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.**"*. Your code is not testable actually, provide your complete function code please.

Comment: You are updating an ACF field in the current WP post, but you are doing that in a loop. Are you sure that you are referencing the right post each time?

Comment: I'm reading the order field inside the loop without having to add the order_id as a parameter. Then in the same loop I want to write back into the same field I just read and it doesn't work! I also tried adding the $order_id as a parameter but that doesn't make any difference... I tried every possible way, not sure what else to try.

Comment: @DanielS Were you able to solve this issue? I am also experiencing same problem.